# Which of the Stack Exchange sites is the best site to ask questions on about how to make large button in a GUI for the visually impaired?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, accessibility

I want to make buttons in GUI very large, but it is unclear which Stack Exchange website to ask this question on.

Potential motivators include:

- creating easy-to-read buttons for persons with disabilities (e.g. 25% blindness)
- ensuring that persons with unimpaired vision can still read code and button labels on low resolution, highly compressed videos
- ensuring that someone sitting at the back of a crowded lecture hall in a college auditorium could still read the IDE buttons and see what the professor is doing.
- creating educational videos for middle-school and high-school students on computer programming.

On which Stack Exchange website would it be best to post a question about how to create large, highly visible buttons? [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) is **not** an appropriate site in which to ask such questions.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by how to _make_ or _create_ them? If you mean _designing_ appropriate buttons for visually impaired users then see [ux.se] as below. If you're _implementing_ a UI given such a design, it'll depend what you're building it in - if you've had a specific problem doing so, SO _may_ be appropriate. If you're an end user of some program and want to _customise_ its UI for legibility that may not be on topic for SE at all.

Comment: [Stack Exchange sites are ***not*** forums](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828)

Comment: Click on the B/L corner of the visual component and drag it to make it bigger?  Edit the Height/Width properties?

Answer (score 6):

The right Stack Exchange site for this is [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/). They have popular tags for [usability](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usability), [gui-design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gui-design), and [accessibility](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accessibility).